# Strange behaviour when accessing private attribute in C++

Tags: c++

I experienced a strange behaviour trying to access a private attribute. Consider the following code:

```
class CLASSE
{
    private:
         int X;
    public:
         CLASSE(int x) { X = x; }
         int  GetX(){ return X; }
         void CopyFrom(CLASSE Src){ X = Src.X; }
};

main ()
{
 CLASSE A = 123;
 CLASSE B = 456;

 cout << "A = " << A.GetX() << endl;
 cout << "B = " << B.GetX() << endl << endl;

 A.CopyFrom (B);
 cout << "A = " << A.GetX() << endl;
 // cout << "A = " << A.X << endl; *** ERROR: CLASSE::X is private
}
```

In the main(), trying to access private attribute X correctly returns an error. I was expecting the same in this situation instead, access to private attribute X in method CopyFrom is allowed (but i'd expect an error). The code has been tested both on DevC and Codeblocks.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Access modifiers don't care about instance, only about type. If you can access `this->X`, they can access any other `CLASS`'s `X`.

Comment: The keyword `private` means that no-one outside this _class_ can read it, not outside this _object_.

Comment: You might still choose to write a definition of `CopyFrom` that calls `GetX`, even though you're able to read `X` directly. That's more a matter of coding style, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every method of a class has access to all its data members, including private members.

**EDIT**: as @StoryTeller mentioned, they also has access to private members of other objects of the same class.

This is also true for private member functions .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you point me to a reference regarding this aspect?

Comment: “The private members are not accessible outside the class; they can be accessed only through methods of the class.” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes